# preventing script reloading in asp.net

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading

Is there any way to prevent loading the same script in asp.net?
Before I load any javascript file I want to check if that has been already loaded or not.
I am using

> Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude

to load javascript files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
if( !Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered("myScript") )
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("myScript", "url");
```